# converting currency in java from float to integer

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to convert currency(float number, dollar, cent) in Java to integer(only cent) on the following way:

```
1.01 = 101
1.99 = 199
```

and so on

What would be the easiest way?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.01 * 100 = 101?

Comment: multiply by 100

Comment: depending on what you want to achieve, if might be best not to use float for currencies: you will lose accuracy. If accuracy is important, use `BigDecimal` the whole way through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406881/regarding-java-string-dollar-to-cents-conversion

Comment: Not a duplicate of that as we don't have strings here.

Comment: Are you 100% sure, you will stick to $? There are currencies with 3 decimals and with no cents.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
public int convertDollarsToCents(float dollars) {
    return Math.round(dollars * 100f);
}
```

Comment: @MarkusBenko That's due to using floats, the method itself is quite good :)

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it :-).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when dealing with currency. It's not recommended to keep money as a floating-point value, but if you no say in how it was stored and want to convert it to cents, round the value after multiplication.

```
int cents = Math.round(money*100f);
```

Without rounding you'll truncate the value which will result in off-by-one cent errors.